# How can I connect Visual Studio 2012 to my WAMP Server MySQL?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, odbc

I've been trying to figure this out for about an hour now.  I downloaded the 64-bit MSI installer for Windows found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).  Then I added the ODBC Data Source called "MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver" to the System DSN's.  The connection to the database was successful.  Now, when I try to add the data connection to VS 2012, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

It sounds pretty self explanatory, but which software do I need to update?  Am I missing a step?